# i want to crete new blog site

Tags: php, mysql, blogs

any free blog engines which I can use for creating new blog site like  gizmodo.com

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90802/simple-free-php-blog-engine-easy-to-redesign

Answer (score 2):

Check out [wordpress.com](http://www.wordpress.com)

Answer (score 2):

I believe [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) is the kind of thing you're looking for.

Comment: Wordpress is two things: .org if you want to download/install/customize your own, .com if you want them to host your blog.wordpress.com. .com is less customizable, but easier to manage.